# How to avoid creating hyperlink in XSL on some values?

Tags: xslt

I have a report that is being generated from the following XSL code. The code generates hyperlink on each number, but I want to avoid creating hyperlink if the value of the variable is zero. Here is my code. Please let me know how can I avoid creating hyperlink when the value is zero

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Image = '' and not(ValueId = '0')">
        <TD style='background-color:#FF6360'>
            <xsl:variable name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="ValueId"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="URL">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('https://google.com/imp/values.aspx?id=', $value)"/>
            </xsl:variable> 
            <a href="{$URL}">
                <xsl:value-of select="ValueId"/>
            </a>
        </TD>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would test if the value of variable $value is 0 and only if it is not equal to 0 it would create the link:

```
<xsl:if test="$value!=0">
    <a href="{$URL}">
         <xsl:value-of select="ValueId"/>
    </a>
</xsl:if>
```

If the type of $value is not a number, the test should be

```
test="$value!='0'"
```

Problem in your current code is that you do not generate a table cell if the value is zero - surely you'll want to generate the td even if the value is zero?
Als you seem to have some unnecessary code: first you make a variable for $value that gets initialized by ValueId. You could have done all that in one go directly with ValueId.